# ALB Ingress controller redirect to different domain name for non API requests

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I would like to setup a redirect from `test.my_old_domain.com` to `data-test.my_new_domain.com` only for web  requests, but all requests which contain `/api` should not be redirected, for example,  `test.my_old_domain.com/api` should not be redirected to `data-test.my_new_domain.com`

I have the below ingress definition

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sbackend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=150
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions: '[{"Field": "host-header", "HostHeaderConfig": {"Values": ["test.my_old_domain.com"]}}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions: '[{"Type": "fixed-response", "FixedResponseConfig": {"ContentType": "text/plain", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301", "ContentType": "text/plain", "Content": "Moved Permanently", "Headers": {"location": "https://data-test.my_new_domain.com"}}}]'
    namespace: staging
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.my_old_domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: backend
              servicePort: 80
    - host: csv.my_old_domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: csv-exporter
              servicePort: 80
    - host: data-test.my_new_domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: backend
              servicePort: 80
    - host: data-export-test.my_new_domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: csv-exporter
              servicePort: 80
```

But this does not work, any help in how this can be achieved will be great, Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your ingress is currently configured to route all paths to the backend or csv-exporter service. I think you need a rule for the /api path.